# Automount USB Memory Stick in Buster (not Lite)

Tags: usb, mount, raspbian-buster

When I insert a USB memory stick a window opens, as expected, inviting me to "Open in File Manager".

However, when I press OK, I get a message:

*The specified directory '/media/pi/E1D1-A752' is not valid*

where E1D1-A752 is the id of the memory stick. The subfolder is not created.

I am running the system from an SSD on a RPi4, where I have copied  the system from the SD card, and changed cmdline.txt in the SD /boot folder to run the system from the SSD, as described on many websites.

The following are results after receipt of the error message:

```
dmesg | grep sd
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 cma=64M cma=256M video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080M@60,margin_left=48,margin_right=48,margin_top=48,margin_bottom=48 smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:16:71:36 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=ce9e8b45-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles root=/dev/sda1 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait usb-storage.quirks=152d:0583:u
[    0.851135] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.851144] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.851970] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    0.907858] sdhci-iproc fe340000.emmc2: Linked as a consumer to regulator.1
[    0.943111] Waiting for root device /dev/sda1...
[    4.934978] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[    4.935625] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    4.935639] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 47 00 00 08
[    4.936288] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    4.938879]  sda: sda1
[    4.941439] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    5.073733] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    7.538109] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    8.709790] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    8.816478] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    8.946344] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[  124.577214] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  124.577286] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 62668800 512-byte logical blocks: (32.1 GB/29.9 GiB)
[  124.577931] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  124.577942] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  124.578601] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  124.578611] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  124.582729]  sdb: sdb1
[  124.585599] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  125.024073] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

and:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 29.9 GiB, 32086425600 bytes, 62668800 sectors
Disk model: USB Flash Drive 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          32 62668799 62668768 29.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I can mount the memory stick manually without problems.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the results from `dmesg | grep sd` and `fdisk -l /dev/sda` commands. What's the filesystem format on your USB stick?

Comment: Jon G: If you have lost login credentials and wish to continue with this question, please create a new account and read *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)*.  If you haven't lost them, you need to login before you can edit.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue described. The /media/pi folder was owned by root, so presumably subfolders could not be created. I did:

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/pi
```

and all works correctly.

---

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all:

> Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.

Go ahead and run `sudo fsck -a /dev/sdb1`. Another option is to plug the thumb drive in a Windows PC and go to Drive context menu -> Properties -> Tools -> Check.